# Java concurrency multi read / atom write

Tags: java, concurrency

i'm trying to implement a cuncurrent read / atomic write in java.

```
static int atom = 0;

static boolean flag = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {

  new Thread(new Reader()).start();
  new Thread(new Reader()).start();
  new Thread(new Reader()).start();

  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      write();
    }
  }, 3000);
}

static void write() {
  flag = true;

  Thread.sleep(1000);
  atom++;

  flag = false;
}

static class Reader implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(5);

      if (flag) {
        continue;
      }

      System.out.println(atom);
    }
  }
}
```

When my threads read the atom var, reads are done until flag is marked true, and continue after value change when flag is turned off.

What is the best way to do this? using sync blocks?

Thanks, Phaedra.

Comment: Prefer `AtomicInteger` and be sure to call `getAndIncrement` to atomically increment your shared variable.

Answer (score 3):

Multi-part answer. In part 1, I'll answer the actual question. In part 2, I'll editorialize a bit.

---

What you have here is all sorts of racy, including data races. You don't have any happens-before orderings, so the JIT would be perfectly within its rights to turn this:

```
while(true) {
    ...
    if (flag) {...}
}
```

Into this:

```
boolean flagCache = flag;
while(true) {
    if (flagCache) { ... }
}
```

Note that `flagCache` isn't ever updated in the second version. The JVM isn't obligated to update it, because `flag` isn't marked as `volatile`.

Beyond that, you've got the race condition in `write` which you seem to have noticed, and a `synchronized` block could indeed help there. The approach would be to create a separate `private static final Object lock = new Object()` and then synchronize on that within the `write` method. That way, writes will synchronize on that object while reads will not. If you go this route, you should also mark `atom` as `volatile`. And you definitely don't need or want the `Thread.sleep(1000)` in that `write` method, especially not within a `synchronized` block. That will create a big-time bottleneck if you've got any sort of concurrency on the writes.

(Marking `atom` as `volatile` is actually not strictly needed if you do things right [you could piggyback off of the happens-before guarantees that reading from `volatile flag` gives you], but that's a subtle and tricky maneuver that is best avoided unless you're really trying to optimize the heck out of it, and also consider yourself an advanced programmer in terms of JMM/concurrency.)

Speaking of bottlenecks, your `Thread.sleep(5)` within your [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) loop is worth mentioning as an interesting tradeoff. Without it, read threads could spin a lot, wasting CPU. But with it, they could spin *too* much for no reason. But actually, you don't need the `flag` at all, or the busy-wait loop. If you just mark `atom` as `volatile` and synchronize its writes, then its reads will come through fine. There's a happens-before edge between writing to a volatile field and reading from it.

---

But I think @Damian Jeżewski is right here. An `AtomicInteger` does the trick simply, easily and more efficiently (since it uses a [compare and set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instead of a blocking, potentially context-switching `synchronized` block).

The general approach to multithreading should almost always be to try and use high-level constructs (ie, things in `java.util.concurrent.*`) before using low-level ones (like `volatile` or even `synchronized`, and definitely before `Object.wait/notify`). That's not a hard and fast rule, of course -- just a general guideline. In this case, look how much thought had to go into a pretty simple requirement -- thread-safe writes with highly concurrent reads -- that `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet` gives you for "free".

Comment: +1 for (among other things) the last pargraph - words of wisdom ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to use `AtomicInteger` from `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package?

Comment: java.util.concurrent.atomic has also something like AtomicReference

Answer (score 1):

You need to `synchronize` on the class, or declare `flag` and `atom` as `volatile` variables, otherwise the concurrent modifications performed by one thread are not guaranteed to be visible on the others.

You may also use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a count of 1, instead of waiting until `flag` is `true`.

Comment: You should only sync the increment (`atom++`), the assignments (`flag=true`,etc) and the variable reads (`if (flag)`, `println(atom)`). Then the threads will execute concurrently, but they will be free of race conditions.

Also note that `flag` is initialized as `false`, then the `Reader` may never enter the loop, if `run` is executed before `write`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems in the code.
1. atom++ introduces the race condition [as explained here](http://fearlessdeveloper.com/race-condition-concurrency-problems/)
2. *flag* value updated by writer may not become immediately visible to reader
3. *atom* value updated by writer may not become immediately visible to reader

Here are 2 simple steps required to turn it thread safe.

1. As pointed out by Damien, make *atom* AtomicInteger.
2. Mark *flag* volatile